# cv::Mat memory leak with opencv 3.x.x, doesn't appear with opencv 2.4.9

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm seeing that if I have a Mat returned from imread, and I pass that into a function (3rd party function, no way of knowing exactly what is going on), I'm leaking memory if I use opencv 3. I've tested on versions 3.3.0, 3.4.3 & 3.4.6 in release.

But the same snippet of code doesn't leak any memory if I'm using opencv 2. I've tested with opencv 2.4.9 in release.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

void Test(const cv::Mat &testImage);
int main()
{
    while (true) 
    {
        cv::Mat testImage = cv::imread("test.png", cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);
        Test(testImage);
    }
}
```

Some additional information, whatever Test() is doing, it increments the Mat's refcount by 2 with opencv 3. And even though cv::Mat.release() set's it to 0, I'm still seeing memory leak. If I check refcount with opencv 2.4.9 Mat, it's 1 after Test().

```
//opencv 3.4.3

int RefCount = testImage.u ? testImage.u->refcount : 0;

std::cout << RefCount << "\n";

testImage.release();

RefCount = testImage.u ? testImage.u->refcount : 0;

std::cout << RefCount << "\n";
```

Output:

```
2
0
```

My question is, is there any way that I can properly dispose of the cv::Mat, in the event that the function is storing a reference to it?

UPDATE:
I've figured out a temporary workaround. It appears that the way the cv::Mat is constructed determines when the deallocation of the cv::Mat is neccesary. So this works:

```
cv::Mat testImage = cv::imread("test.png", cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH); 

cv::Mat testImage0(testImage.rows, testImage.cols, CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U, testImage.channels()), testImage.data);

Test(testImage0);
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: But what if that 3rd party function stores a reference to the mat? That doesn't count as a leak. [mcve] please.

Comment: Another possibility is that the function contain a bug and it happens to be fine in opencv 2

Comment: My question is, is there any way that I can properly dispose of the cv::Mat? In the event that the function is storing a reference to it.

Comment: Forcefully releasing the memory of the `cv::Mat` is done by calling `mat.deallocate()`. But if that `Test()` function is keeping a reference to the `cv::Mat` after returning then you need to find out whether the intent of that function was to take ownership of the memory or not. That third party code may attempt to access the image after you've deallocated it.

Comment: @Romen, if I'm not mistaken .deallocate() should do the same thing as .release(). Either way, the application is still leaking memory when .deallocate() is called. Also I know enough about the 3rd party function that it definitely shouldn't access the image after the function call. And it doesn't with opencv 2, thats clear with looking at refcount.

Comment: @mSours, FYI `release()` doesn't call `deallocate()` if there are still references, so calling deallocate directly gives you a guarantee that the memory freed. You're saying that deallocate does *not* free the memory though?

Comment: @Romen Yeah that's correct. I tried .deallocate() instead of .release() and I'm still seeing that the memory is not freed. 

I figured out a workaround that. It seems that the way the cv::Mat is constructed makes a difference. If I do:



cv::Mat testImage = cv::imread("test.png", cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);
        Test(testImage);

cv::Mat testImage0testImage.rows, testImage.cols, CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U, testImage.channels()), testImage.data);

That works, and the memory is freed after the function call.

Comment: @mSours, Yes the way `cv::Mat` is created determines whether it is responsible for automatically deallocating its pixel data. Calling `deallocate()` should *always* free the memory though. Can you make a minimal reproducible example without the third-party code showing that `imread` and then `deallocate` leaks?

Comment: @mSours, Can you just show or tell us where this third party `Test()` function comes from?